# Create a new element by selenium dynamically

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

What I need is to add a script tag to the head of html document. I am using the code below but when I view page source, the script is not there.
Thank you in advance,

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.x.org")


execu = '''
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.type = 'text/javascript';
scr.text = `let calls = (function(){
    let calls = 0;
    let fun = document.createElement;
    document.createElement = function(){
      calls++;
      return fun.apply(document, arguments);
    }
    return ()=>calls;
})();`
document.head.appendChild(scr);
'''
try:
    driver.execute_async_script(execu)
except Exception,e:
    print str(e)
```

Comment: the scripts will not be added to the *page source*. The page source is the html that was returned by `www.x.org`.

Comment: So, You mean I cannot add a script to page by executescript() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely you can add `script` tag into `HEAD` dynamically by selenium `execute_script` api,  please try below simple code. if it work, you can change the `scr.text` to your content

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.x.org")
// sleep 10 seconds wait page load complete
// you should change to wait in official script
time.sleep(10)

execu = '''
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.type = 'text/javascript';
scr.text = 'alert("yes")';
document.head.appendChild(scr);
'''
try:
    driver.execute_script(execu) // if it work, an alert with 'yes' should display

    // sleep for a long time, so that you have more time to 
    // check the script tag appended into head tag or not.
    // only for debug purpose
    time.sleep(30)

except Exception,e:
    print str(e)
```

Please execute below 4 lines one by one in DevTool's Console Tab:

[image]

If You can get an alert, an inserted `script` tag in HTML `head`, it means the javascript snippet worked fine on your browse, the failure should comes from other python code lines

[image]

Comment: Thank you but your code is just the same as mine except for time.sleep(). it does not work, I mean it seems that it executes successfully but when I view page source the script is not there.