# Convert img with alt attribute to text with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the element below with text and images between the texts.

```
<span class="emojis">
    Lol emojis: 
    <img alt="" ... />
    <img alt="" ... />
    Hands emojis: 
    <img alt="" ... />
    <img alt="" ... />
</span>
```

But when I use `.text`:

```
emojis = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="emojis"]').text
```

I get only text between the images:

```
Lol emojis: Hands emojis:
```

I know that `.get_attribute('alt')` get the text of the `alt` attribute, but...

**Is there any way to get the text in the `alt` attribute and replace the `<img>` element with the corresponding text and join the `<span>` texts with the emojis in the right order to get the text below?**

```
Lol emojis:  Hands emojis:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all emojis in `alt` and use this to sets HTML contents (text) using `execute_script` and `innerHTML`:

```
emojis_imgs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="emojis"]/img')
for emoji_img in emojis_imgs:
   emoji = emoji_img.get_attribute('alt')
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = arguments[1];", emoji_img, emoji)
```

Now I can get the text with emoctions in right order:

```
text_with_emojis = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="emojis"]').text
```

Output:

```
Lol emojis:  Hands emojis:
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the text from the alt attribute use:

```py
webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="emojis"]').get_attribute('alt')
```

I am a bit confused when you say "replace the  element with the corresponding text?"

If you want to add a new `<p>` or `<h1>` tag you'll have to use the execute_script function with some JavaScript. Try to use this solution:  [Create a new element by selenium dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861078/create-a-new-element-by-selenium-dynamically)

Comment: The intention is to join the text with the emojis in the right order. I know that get_attribute gets the attribute, but that doesn't solve it. Output should be: "Lol emojis:  Hands emojis: "

Answer (score 0):

To get the `alt` attribute value you need to identify the `image` tag and then use `element.get_attribute("alt"))`

```
for img in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='emojis']//img"):
    print(img.get_attribute("alt"))
```

### **UPDATE:**

It's bit tricky to do it via selenium. However still you can do that using `java scripts executor` and child nodes. However I believe this kind of **usecase** you have to manipulate, since there is no generic way you could achieve it via selenium.

```
val1=driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[0].textContent;', driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='emojis']")).strip()
val2=driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[1];', driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='emojis']")).get_attribute("alt")
val3=driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[3];', driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='emojis']")).get_attribute("alt")
val4=driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[4].textContent;', driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='emojis']")).strip()
val5=driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[5]', driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='emojis']")).get_attribute("alt")
val6=driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[7]', driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='emojis']")).get_attribute("alt")
print(val1 + " " + val2 + " " + val3 + " " + val4 + " " + val5 +" " +val6)
```

**Expected output:**

```
Lol emojis:   Hands emojis:
```

It would have been easier with beautifulsoup.

Comment: How to join emojis with texts in the right order to output: Lol emojis:  Hands emojis: ?

Comment: Okay, that answers. But what if the order of texts and emojis is random?

Comment: @Slowaways : Please read my updated answer carefully `However I believe this kind of usecase you have to manipulate, since there is no generic way you could achieve it via selenium`

Answer (score -1):

Try use below code to get required output:

```
java_script = """var emojis = [];
                 var spanChildNodes = document.querySelector('span.emojis').childNodes;
                 for (i = 0; i < spanChildNodes.length; i++) {if (spanChildNodes[i].textContent != '') {emojis.push(spanChildNodes[i].textContent)} else emojis.push(spanChildNodes[i].getAttribute('alt'))};
                 return emojis;"""

emojis = [elem.strip() for elem in driver.execute_script(java_script)]
print(" ".join(emojis))
```

Output:

```
Lol emojis:    Hands emojis:
```